# PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

I am not able to define an alias or to choose specific columns, works only with wildcard:

Working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) *  
FROM public.server AS s
LEFT JOIN public.Report AS r ON s.Id = r.ServerId
ORDER BY r.InsertDate DESC;
```

Not working :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) LastReport, s.Id, s.Servername 
FROM public.server AS s
LEFT JOIN public.Report AS r ON s.Id = r.ServerId
ORDER BY r.InsertDate DESC;
```

Error

```
ERROR:  column "lastreport" does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) LastReport, s.Id, s.Serve...
                                           ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 36
```

Also not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) , s.Id, s.Servername 
FROM public.server AS s
LEFT JOIN public.Report AS r ON s.Id = r.ServerId
ORDER BY r.InsertDate DESC;
```

```
ERROR:  column "lastreport" does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) LastReport, s.Id, s.Serve...
                                           ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 36

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1:  SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) , s.Id, s.Servername 
                                           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 36
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about `DISTINCT ON`.  It does not "return a column".  It is a syntactic construct.  These are variations of the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT ON ()
```

(The first is the default and never used in practice.)

The column list *follows* these constructs.  So, apparently you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.InsertDate) r.InsertDate as LastReport, s.Id, s.Servername 
FROM public.server s LEFT JOIN
     public.Report r
     ON s.Id = r.ServerId
ORDER BY r.InsertDate DESC;
```

It turns out that `DISTINCT ON` is actually parsed after the rest of the `SELECT` clause, so you can use column aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (LastReport) r.InsertDate as LastReport, s.Id, s.Servername 
FROM public.server s LEFT JOIN
     public.Report r
     ON s.Id = r.ServerId
ORDER BY LastReport DESC;
```

However, the alias must be defined in the column list after the `distinct on`.

Note that you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, so `r.InsertDate` *could* be `NULLL`.

Comment: Thank you, my hero today :)